# Regex match inline javascript

Tags: javascript, php, regex, preg-match

How do I extract inline javascripts like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">...fetch-me...</script>
<script type="application/javascript">...fetch-me...</script>
<script>...fetch-me...</script>
```

But avoid matching non-javascript and external resources:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
<script src="file.js"></script>
<script type="application/ld+json">...</script>
```

This did not do the trick for me:

```
#<script(?:[^>]*\stype="(?:application|text)/javascript")?[^>]*>(.*?)</script>#isg
```

https://regex101.com/r/kR1vY6/2

Comment: @chris85 The rules are to match any variant of inline javascript and exclude any non-javascript code and external resources. The g flag in PHP is redundant as it's always performing the search globally. I inserted the g operator to make the regex universal no matter of PHP. I don't think the right answer is dependant of PHP or not as this is a question of regular expressions and their positive and/or negative lookaheads.

Comment: Why would you wanna add the g operator to PHP? The documentation already states. preg_match_all — Perform a global regular expression match. Wanna throw this in PHP? Don't throw in the g. Nuff said.